# Class static method returning struct containing object of this class

Tags: c++

I've got a class:

```
class SOMECLASS
{
    public:
        (...)
        static SOMESTRUCT GetInfo();

};
```

And a struct:

```
struct SOMESTRUCT
{
    (...)
    SOMECLASS Instance;
};
```

They are declared in SOMESTRUCT.h and SOMECLASS.h

I'm not able to compile it, even with forward declarations.
I'm still getting:

```
error: field ‘Instance’ has incomplete type
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: `SOMECLASS` does not need a complete type, so use a forward declaration of `SOMESTRUCT`. `SOMESTRUCT` needs a complete type, so make `SOMECLASS`'s definition available.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

SOMECLASS.h

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#DEFINE SOMECLASS_H

class SOMECLASS
{
    public:
        (...)
        static struct SOMESTRUCT GetInfo();

};
#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

SOMESTRUCT,h

```
#ifndef SOMESTRUCT_H
#DEFINE SOMESTRUCT_H

#include "SOMECLASS.h"

struct SOMESTRUCT
{
    (...)
    SOMECLASS Instance;
};

#endif // SOMESTRUCT_H
```

Comment: Is it the same as using #pragma once?

Comment: @peku33 #pragma once is not a standard feature. Nevertheless if your compiler provides it then you can use it.

Comment: it's gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5), I'm getting following error: Classes/SOMECLASS.cpp:27:84: error: return type ‘struct SOMESTRUCT’ is incomplete

Comment: @peku33 Module SOMECLASS.cpp shall include the both headers before the function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given above would have been correct if the users include SOMESTRUCT.h.
If the user do this

```
#include "SOMECLASS.h"
int main()
{
    SOMECLASS::GetInfo();
}
```

The same error would occur.

The reason is the compiler has to know the full definition of the return variable; otherwise it cannot know how to construct it when the function returns.

When SOMECLASS.h is included, the compiler only knows the identifier SOMESTRUCT is a sturct. If the user calls SOMECLASS::GetInfo, the function has to construct a SOMESTRUCT, so the full definition of the struct has to be given before that line in the same file.

To solve it, it is more reasonable to include SOMESTRUCT.h in SOMECLASS.h, so the user can be sure that calling any function in the class would not result in compilation error, as long as they include the header.
One should also forward declare class SOMECLASS in SOMESTRUCT.h.

If there are cases that only SOMESTRUCT.h is used, then the SOMECLASS.h should also be included in SOMESTRUCT.h, because constructing SOMESTRUCT requires the definition of SOMECLASS.h.
You could avoid this is by declaring Instance variable as SOMECLASS& or SOMECLASS* instead of SOMECLASS.

---

If you really don't want to expose the detailed definition of the SOMESTRUCT, you can try these

1. define an IInfo interface class with virtual accessor to get information from SOMESTRUCT
2. use pimpl idiom

By these ways you don't have to include SOMESTRUCT.h in SOMECLASS.h.